# QuickFIX/J: Not receiving ExecutionReport messages

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

After opening an order with our brokerage firm, we desire to obtain the fill price from the `ExecutionReport` messages. Below you will find the callback code used.

The `MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh` messages are received properly, but the second `if` block is never triggered. Strangely, the corresponding messages.log file does contain multiple `35=8` messages.

We use QuickFIX/J as FIX engine.

```
@Override
public void fromApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType {
    if (message instanceof MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh) {
        // do stuff with MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh
    }

    if(message instanceof ExecutionReport) {
        // do stuff with ExecutionReport
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message handling is ideally done by a [`quickfix.MessageCracker`](https://www.quickfixj.org/javadoc/1.6.4//quickfix/MessageCracker.html), though sometimes handling them in `fromApp` is the way to go.

You can read more about message cracking here: [QuickFIX/J User Manual - Receiving Messages](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.3/usage/receiving_messages.html).

I'll outline both ways:

---

1. **In `fromApp`**

   Messages coming in `fromApp` are not of specific message types as defined in the QuickFIX/J library, but are of type `quickfix.Message`. If you wanted to process them the way you are doing now (from `fromApp`), you would have to inspect the `MsgType` manually:

   ```
   MsgType msgType = (MsgType) message.getHeader( ).getField( new MsgType( ) );
   ```

   Based on the type retrieved, you would call a handler method for the specific message type:

   ```
   if( msgType.valueEquals( MsgType.MARKET_DATA_SNAPSHOT_FULL_REFRESH ) )
       handleMarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh( message, sessionID );
   else if ...

   ...

   private void handleMarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh( quickfix.Message msg, SessionID sessionID ) {
       // handler implementation
   }
   ```

---

2. **Using `MessageCracker`**

   Another way to handle incoming messages as mentioned before, is through a  `MessageCracker`. You would e.g. extend the class that implements `quickfix.Application` with `quickfix.MessageCracker`.

   Add an `onMessage` method with two parameters, first being the message type, second a SessionID. Call `crack` from the `fromApp` method which will route to the appropriate handler.

   ```
   import quickfix.*;

   public class MyApplication extends MessageCracker implements Application
   {
       public void fromApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID)
             throws FieldNotFound, UnsupportedMessageType, IncorrectTagValue {
             crack(message, sessionID);
       }

       @Handler
       public void onMessage(quickfix.fix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh mdsfr, SessionID sessionID) {
            // handler implementation
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing the message processing in the wrong place ? If you check what is recommended by Quickfix you will see they recommend message processing happens in `onMessage` (which you might not have implemented). And there should only exist a message cracker in fromApp method.

Or else your fromApp method is going to be a hotchpotch of code and the next person handling your code is not going to be a happy soul.